# CsvHelper: modify a string before loading it into a ClassMap?

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

Using CsvHelper v29, when creating a ClassMap, is it possible to modify a string before it is loaded into the map?

For example, in the code below, `m.EmployeeNumber` is of type `string?` and it may have a value of `"001234"`:

```
    public sealed class CsvMap : ClassMap<Employee>
    {
        public CsvMap()
        {
            _ = Map(m => m.EmployeeNumber);
            ...
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to convert its value using `Map()` to `"=001234"`.

I have tried:
`_ = Map(m => m.EmployeeNumber?.Prepend('='));`

But this will not work because an expression tree lambda cannot have the null propagating operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bigger issue is that `Map` is expecting the expression to return a class member, for example `EmployeeNumber`. You would need to use `Convert` to actually change the output.

```cs
_ = Map(m => m.EmployeeNumber).Convert(args => "=" + args.Value.EmployeeNumber);
```